# Google play icon not appearing (fontawsome)

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I want to add google play and apple icons with the download button
the apple icon works fine but the google play doesn't show and i don' know why

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<h1>Meet new and interesting dogs nearby.</h1>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-dark btn-lg"><i class="fa fa-apple"></i>Download</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-light btn-lg"><i class="fab fa-google-play"></i>Download 2</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cause you're using fontawsome version 4.7.0 and the google play icon is version 5.0.0. Here is the correct code you must use instead.

You must also change the class of the apple icon to `fab fa-apple` cause it's for version 5.8.0 of fontawsome.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css">
<h1>Meet new and interesting dogs nearby.</h1>
<!-- <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark btn-lg"><i class="fa fa-apple"></i>Download</button> -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-dark btn-lg"><i class="fab fa-apple"></i>Download</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-light btn-lg"><i class="fab fa-google-play"></i>Download 2</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just replace the link with the following:
Your code will work just fine.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-50oBUHEmvpQ+1lW4y57PTFmhCaXp0ML5d60M1M7uH2+nqUivzIebhndOJK28anvf" crossorigin="anonymous">
```